# how to display data in crystal reports using mysql command conditional statement?

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I am having a problem displaying conditional statement on my crystal reports. I want to display those customers who has a **"Paid"** status but it seems that my code didn't work because it still displays all of my data from database.

```
        MySqlConnection conn;
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter adap;

        conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=order&billing; " +
            "User ID=root; Password=; charset=utf8;"); conn.Open();
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select `order`.or_no,`order`.balance,`order`.totalprice, `order`.paid,customer.fname,customer.lname,customer.addr, customer.status, caterselected.catsel from `order` left join customer on `order`.custid=customer.custid left join caterselected on caterselected.nserveid=`order`.nserveid where `customer`.status='Paid'";

        adap = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adap.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet1 custDB = new DataSet1();
        custDB.Clear();
        adap.Fill(custDB, "cust");



        CrystalReport1 myReport = new CrystalReport1();
        myReport.SetDataSource(custDB); 
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;
```

[image: Here is my dataset1]
*And this is the output of my crystal reports*
[image: crystalreports]

Comment: Are you sure that SQL command is correct? You're only grouping on one field and the other items you're selecting are neither in this grouping nor are they aggregates. I'd have thought MySQL would have objected to this.

Comment: You may also want `customer.status = paid` as a WHERE condition rather than part of the join.

Comment: yes Ceisc my sqlcommand was correct i tried this sql on my sqlcommand in sqlmanager before i put it in here. i am very sure it is working

Comment: As far as I see by your explnation query is generating correct result on database and not working on crystal reports.. so I would like to ask whether your `Paid` is only this name as it is without any uppercase or lowercase combination.. one more thing that come to my mind is use the `Record Selection Formula` in crystal reports instead of `Where` clause in crystal reports and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

You are using somewhat strange filtering logic in your SQL query.  This is the query.

```
select `order`.or_no,
       `order`.balance,
       `order`.totalprice,
       `order`.paid,
       customer.fname,
       customer.lname,
       customer.addr,
       customer.status,
       caterselected.catsel
  from `order` 
  left join customer on `order`.custid=customer.custid
  left join caterselected on caterselected.nserveid=`order`.nserveid
 where `customer`.status='Paid'
```

This `where` clause pulls selects *customer* rows with a paid status, and incidentally converts the `left join customer` clause to an `inner join customer` clause by putting a filter condition on the left table.

But there's nothing in your tables (that I can see) requiring a customer with Paid status to have only orders with Paid status. You haven't explained your business logic sufficiently for us to understand what it means for a Paid customer to have an Unpaid order.

What happens if you use this WHERE clause instead?

```
 where `order`.status='Paid'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myReport.SetDataSource(custDB.Tables(0));
```